# Java issue that i dont understand

Tags: java, class, object

i am sorry that i might seem dumb but im new java as i am studying it in high school:

```
public class One
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.print ("One");
    }
}

public class Two extends One
{
    public void display ()
    {
        System.out.print("Two");
    }
}
```

> What is printed after the following code segment is executed?
>
> ```
> One object1= new Two();
> object1.display();
> ```
>
> 1. OneTwo
> 2. TwoOne
> 3. Two
> 4. One
> 5. No output

Can anyone please help me with answering the question above,  i have read a lot about objects and classes and how they operate and how subclasses work but i cannot figure this question, plx help.

Edit: This is an AP computer Science A question i dont really have a tutor/teacher to reach out to most of java was self-studied for me, so i would consider myself as a beginner to java but i got a lot covered, thanks for the help!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it. Also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: In addition to what @Pshemo said, you also have a teacher who is being paid to teach you. They should be the one you're going to with questions about your assignment. They are in the best position to understand what they've asked, and they also need to know where you're having difficulties so they can adjust their lesson plans for improvement.

Comment: It will print "Two" because you Override the inherited method. If you want to access the super implementation, in your class Two, call super.display() and it will then also print "One"

Comment: Try it, and you will have your answer yourself :) .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework assignment

Comment: @Ascalonian Problem is not that it is homework (there are many great questions here which are based on homework assignments). Problem is that it is homework dump, question without any *specific* problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The good answer is 3. "Two".**

To understand why, you have to understand polymorphism and overriding:
In your case you have two classes:

```
+------------------+
|        Two       |
+------------------+
          |
        extend
          |
          v
+------------------+
|        One       |
+------------------+
```

All public and protected field from One are visible and overridable by Two.
In your case, `One.display()` is overrided by `Two.display()`.

If the code followed the Java conventions, there should be the annotation [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) on top of the Two.display() method to explicit this behavior to other developers and to the Compiler who's check if the method already exists in the parent object.

I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: Only if code will compile (code from question will not).

Comment: The code from question compile if you create a file One.java with the One class and a file Two.java with the Two Class ;)

Comment: Please test it first by copying code *directly from question*.

Comment: It's just a copy paste problem from his tools... Come on guy !

Comment: Sometimes such problems are intentionally left in homework assignments. I don't know if this one is also the case, but IMO it was worth addressing, which is why I posted first comment. I never said your answer was bad, but simply incomplete :)

Comment: thank you all so much for the help, i apologize as i am new to this website and did not clearly read the highlights about homework assignments so i will fix that in the future, this question is an AP computer Science A question and i dont really have a tutor or teacher most of java is self-studied for me, thank you all so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem actually common problem around high school studies. But you need to just simple think.

The Object class is superclass all of the classes in java. You think something class withoud any extend operation. And again imagine that, this something class has a method called method1. (void or not void. Not important.) When you create an instance in main method, and, when you try to call method1 from this instance, if you use any IDE for java, you will see something methods called notify(), notifyAll(), toString() and etc. This methods are methods of Object classes.

Beside, when you write a code like this

`Object instance = new YourClass();`

and after then, when you write your ide like `instance.`
you can see Object methods.

This is Polymorphism